# Can't unlink Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

We have an iPad 2. It is locked and can't be activated. We can't remember Apple ID and also the e-mail address which we used to create the Apple ID. We can't also find the invoice to prove to the guys at Apple support that the device is ours so they say they could remove the lock remotely.

Is there another way to unlink Apple ID from the device? Or shall I junk it?

iOS version on the device is 9.3.4.

Comment: Have you tried going to [iForgot.Apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com) to see if you can retrieve your account that way? You can even do it if you don't know your AppleID.

Comment: If you're able to login correctly now, please add that as an answer to your own question. That will help others who have the same problem know there's a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Frysk post that as an answer, it evidently worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot remember your AppleID account information, try going to [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com) and see if you can recover your information that way. You can even do it if you do not remember your AppleID!

Answer (score 2):

Finally recovered the Apple ID by going to [iForgot.Apple.com](http://iForgot.Apple.com) and then resetting e-mail password to reuse our e-mail which is linked to Apple ID. After that we reset Apple ID password and now we can use the device.